# Shannon's definition of ergodicity

Tags: probability, information-theory, markov-process, ergodic-theory

In A Mathematical Theory of Communication (1948) Shannon gives a definition of ergodicity for a Markov process. In order to be ergodic the directed graph of the process must have the following characteristics:

```
1. Strongly connected
2. All cycle lengths are coprime.
```

I understand why the first condition is necessary. For the second, Shannon gives the example of a graph with two length three cycles, that always start with the same element, and I understand how this would have periodic structure and thus would violate ergodicity. However, I don't understand how we would necessarily have this periodic structure for any arbitrary set of non coprime cycles. Is there a proof that uses Shannon's definition/some illustration of this concept to help me understand this?

Comment: If all the cycle lengths have some GCD $n > 1$, wouldn't return times other than those $\equiv 0 \bmod n$ be forbidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That the cycle lengths are not coprime means that there is an integer $p>1$ such that the length of every cycle in the graph is a multiple of $p$.  This would imply that a path starting from a state $x$ has the possibility to return to $x$ only after a number of steps that is a multiple of $p$.  More generally, you can partition the set of vertices into disjoint sets $A_0,A_1,\ldots,A_{p-1}$, where $A_i$ is the set of vertices reachable from $x$ in $kp+i$ steps.  Then of course your Markov chain will have a periodic behaviour always going through the cycle $A_0\to A_1\to \cdots\to A_{p-1}\to A_0$.

Comment: With Shannon's definition, what sort of statistical things would this violate if the chain is periodic? Is there an example of some statistical value that would not be the same between different sequences as we limit them?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  That the Markov chain is ergodic means that there is a unique stationary distribution $\mu$, and that the distribution of state at time $t$ converges to $\mu$ as $t\to\infty$, irrespectively of what the starting distribution has been.  That is, if $\pi_t$ denotes the distribution of the state at time $t$, then $\pi(x)\to\mu(x)$ for every state $x$.  This cannot be the case if the Markov chain has the above type of periodicity.

Comment: I think I understand, I looked at the example in these notes: http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-MCII.pdf.